# unable to logoff from the site

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I have came across a strange issue regarding a logoff a user from site with my specific theme. 
When I press the logoff link, then page is refreshed, but user is still logged in. When I changed the site skin to the default provided by the DNN, then there is no problem. 
In completly diffrent site that I created with my custom theme, this links works also. I have disabled the javascript thinking that, maybe some js script mess something but result is the same. 
I don't know where to start looking for this issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling javascript is a problem.  The "logoff" link uses javascript.

GO back to your custom skin with javascript enabled, and use the developer tools to open the Console window.  You should see information there that will help identify the problem.

Comment: I disabled js only for test. And there is no error in firebug/chrome dev tools console.

Answer (score 0):

Try messing with the order and priority of the javascript files in the .ASCX skin control. For example, if you have:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="jquery.one.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="jquery.two.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

Try switching them around, or alternatively try changing their priorities, like so:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="jquery.two.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="100" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="jquery.one.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="150" />
```

Sometimes there is a conflict in the order in which the libraries are loaded, even if it doesn't show up in the console.

You can read more about this in the [Client Resource Management API](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api)

Finally, try comparing the several skins .ASCX files to each other, to see if something is missing in this particular one.